# Changing Data directory in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, directory

I have a doubt :

> Is mariadb support datadirectory location change from the default
>   location to the another user defined location ?

When Iam trying to change datadir location of mariadb by editing the path in the configuration file `my.ini`, after this, restart the mariadb service, but it couldn't started. Only the default(installation) datadir location worked. The same succefully worked with mysql.
Because this is the reason for my doubt...

Please anyone to help me from this issue... (Iam trying in windows)

Comment: Please attach the output of your log files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a distro like redhat/centos then selinux is not letting mariadb write outside of the pre-set data directory.

If you are using something like ubuntu then apparmour is doing the same thing that selinux is doing.

For a quick fix you can try disabling the one in question and then trying.

Answer (score 0):

I am using InnoDB and had the same issue on windows (x64), I got the following error line (don't know what you got):

```
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 52428800 bytes!
```

What helped was deleting the `ib_logfile*` files in the data folder from the new location.
That created new logfiles w/o losing any data in the database.

Comment: ib_logfile*s are InnoDB's binary log, very sensitive topic if this file gets changed or corrupted.